# Getting feature importance by sample - Python Scikit Learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a fitted model (`clf`) using `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`. I already know that I can get the feature importances with `clf.feature_importances_`. Anyway, I would like to know, if it's possible, how to get feature importances but by each sample.

Example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X = {"f1":[0,1,1,0,1], "f2":[1,1,1,0,1]}
y = [0,1,0,1,0]

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

y_pred = clf.predict(X)
```

Then, how do I get something like this:

```
y_pred f1_importance f2_importance
   1         0.57          0.43          
   1         0.26          0.74
   1         0.31          0.69
   0         0.62          0.38
   1         0.16          0.84
```

*** **`y_pred` values aren't real. I'm actually using `pandas` for the real project in Python 3.8.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `treeinterpreter` to get the feature importance for individual predictions of your `RandomForestClassifier`

You can find the `treeinterpreter` on [Github](https://github.com/andosa/treeinterpreter) and install it via

```
pip install treeinterpreter
```

I used your reference code but had to adjust it, because you can not use a dictionary as input to fit your `RandomForestClassifier`:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from treeinterpreter import treeinterpreter as ti
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = np.array([[0,1],[1,1],[1,1],[0,0],[1,1]])
y = [0,1,0,1,0]

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

y_pred = clf.predict(X)
y_pred_probas = clf.predict_proba(X)
```

Then I used the treeinterpreter with your classifier and data to compute the bias, contributions and also the prediction values:

```
prediction, bias, contributions = ti.predict(clf, X)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.matrix([y_pred, prediction.transpose()[0], prediction.transpose()[1], np.sum(contributions, axis=1).transpose()[0], bias.transpose()[0], np.sum(contributions, axis=1).transpose()[1], bias.transpose()[1]]).transpose(), columns=["Prediction", "Prediction value 0", "Prediction value 1", "f1_contribution", "f1_bias", "f2_contribution","f2_bias"])

df
```

**Output**

[image]

You can have a look at [this blogpost](http://blog.datadive.net/random-forest-interpretation-with-scikit-learn/) by the author, to understand better how it works.

In the table the prediction value for 0 and 1 refers to the probability for both classes, which you can also compute by using the existing [predict_proba()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) method of `RandomForestClassifier`.

You can verify, that the bias and contributions add up to the prediction value/probability like this:

```
bias + np.sum(contributions, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
array([[0.744 , 0.256 ],
       [0.6565, 0.3435],
       [0.6565, 0.3435],
       [0.214 , 0.786 ],
       [0.6565, 0.3435]])
```